# How do i Inherit the methods from a class and use them in another activity

Tags: java, android

I have a LoginActivity that checks if user is connected to the internet. And it works perfectly. But now I feel like my activities are full of too much code and would like to separate the internet checker from the Login Activity but im struggling to perform the method calls.

This is what I've tried:

InternetChecker class:

```
public class InternetChecker  {


public void checkNet(){

        if(connected()){
            Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.activity_login), "Your Internet Connection is Great",
                    Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).setActionTextColor(Color.RED).show();
            Log.i("TRUE","User is connected");

        }else{
            Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.activity_login), "Your You are not Connected to the internet",
                    Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).setActionTextColor(Color.RED).show();
            Log.i("TRUE","User is not connected");
        }

    }

    private boolean connected(){
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager=(ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo !=null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }
}
```

In this class I am getting an error on `findViewById` in the method `checkNet();` in the `private boolean connected(){`.

So I solved this by using `extends AppCompatActivity` in my `InternetChecker` class, the errors (`findViewbyId` disappeared).
I am just wondering if this is the correct convention and if not what should i extend?

**But my main question is:**
In my LoginActivity which is meant to inherit the InterneChecker methods:

I have initialized the InternetChecker Class:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private InternetChecker internetChecker = new InternetChecker();
```

Then I tried using InternetChecker inside a method named `checkInternet` which is in my `LoginActivity` class:

```
private void checkInternet(){
            InternetChecker = new InternetChecker();
        }
```

But i am getting the error expression expected on this line:

```
InternetChecker = new InternetChecker();
```

so i tried the following:

```
InternetChecker checkNet = new InternetChecker();
```

There are no errors this time, but CheckNet has a warning: variable checkNet is never used and when i run the app, the app does not call the `InternetChecker` methods and check if user is connected to the internet.

Please guide me on how I can inherit the methods in the class `InternetChecker`, and apply them to `LoginActivity`?

NB: My Manifest has permissions set already:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

**This is mySolution based on a combination of the answers below**

I created a BaseActivity:

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public void checkNet(){

            if(connected()){
                Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.activity_login), "Your Internet Connection is Great",
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).setActionTextColor(Color.RED).show();
                Log.i("TRUE","User is connected");

            }else{
                Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.activity_login), "Your You are not Connected to the internet",
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).setActionTextColor(Color.RED).show();
                Log.i("TRUE","User is not connected");
            }
        }
    private boolean connected(){
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager=(ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo !=null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }
}
```

Then extended the `BaseActivity` in `LoginActivity`

```
public class LoginActivity extends BaseActivity {
```

I then created a method inside `LoginActivity` that calls `checkNet`:

```
private void checkInternet(){
    checkNet();
}
```

Then called this method in my LoginActivity's onCreate:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    checkInternet();
```

But if there are better ways to this than  what I've done here, I would appreciate the answer so I can mark is as the correct answer.

Comment: You forgot the variable name on `InternetChecker = new InternetChecker();`

Comment: I already added the variable in my LoginActivity.

Comment: In your onCreate in LoginActivity.You can call the method checkNet(); directly without creating another method inside called checkInternet.The whole idea is to have as much less code as possible.So you dont need another method calling on checkNet inside LoginActivity

Comment: And another thing,you do realise checkNet();will run and show the snack message each time the app loads right?This can annoy users.Try to create the method to only run once and also display the message if the user is not connected to the net when attempting to perform functions on your app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way would be to make a MiscUtils class

```
public class MiscUtils{
public static isConnected(Context context){
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager=(ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo !=null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
}
```

Now let all your activities extend a BaseActivity, which would extend the AppCompatActivity,

In the BaseActivity,

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    public void showNoInternetMessage(View view){
     Snackbar.make(view, "Your You are not Connected to the internet",
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).setActionTextColor(Color.RED).show();
                Log.i("TRUE","User is not connected");
    }
    }
```

Now from all your activities [Since they extend the BaseActivity], you can just call

```
if(MiscUtils.isConnectedToInternet(this)){
}else{
showNoInternetMessage(//Any view id from this activity);
}
```

Comment: Here i still need extends AppCompatActvity in MiscUtils.Without that i get the error cannot find method getSystemService

Comment: You wont need to extend AppCompatActivity in MiscUtils, if you see the code, MiscUtils, would just let you know whether the internet connection is there or not. The corresponding activity would use the function in the  MiscUtils to check the connection and accordingly call the super function in the BaseActivity to show the message

Answer (score 1):

You can make InternetChecket inherint from `AppCompatActivity` and then make your activity inherit from `InternetChecker`:

```
public class InternetChecker  extends AppCompatActivity{


public void checkNet(){



        if(connected()){
            Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.activity_login), "Your Internet Connection is Great",
                    Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).setActionTextColor(Color.RED).show();
            Log.i("TRUE","User is connected");

        }else{
            Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.activity_login), "Your You are not Connected to the internet",
                    Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).setActionTextColor(Color.RED).show();
            Log.i("TRUE","User is not connected");
        }

    }

private boolean connected(){
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager=(ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo !=null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

and then:

```
public class LoginActivity extends InternetChecker
```

Now all methods in InternetChecker will be available to you in LoginActivity. And InternetChecker can call `findViewById` because it inherits this method from `AppCompatActivity`.

You can also make InternetChecker an utility class which is more common and I personally recommend:

```
public class InternetChecker{

private Context mContext;
public InternetChecker(Context context){
    mContext = context;
}
private boolean connected(){
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager=(ConnectivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo !=null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

And then whenever you want to check connectivity you just do within an activity:

```
InternetChecker checker = new InternetChecker(this);

if(checker.connected()){
//connected
}
```

Comment: LoginActivity already extends AppCompat Activity.How can i use extends more than one class in Login Activity?

Comment: You don't need to make LoginActivity extend AppCompat, it will extend it through InternetChecker

Comment: You just make LoginActivity extend InternetChecker and as InternetChecker extends AppCompatActivity, LoginActivity will also extend that by extension

Comment: Sounds good.But my main aim is to use internetchecker across my entire app.Will i then have to extend intercheck in every class,or should move internet check to an Application class that is used throughout the app.Like we do in the manifest under application launcher?

Comment: From what you've posted from internet check it sounds like it's something your activities will want to use (there's a findviewbyid method call, which belongs inside an activity). So yes, you'll need to inherit that in every activity you want to use the methods.

Comment: What is usually done is to but that piece of code in an Utility class, but for this you'd need to remove all references to methods connected to activities (findviewbyid for example). So instead of showing a Toast you could return true or false (which you already do in the connected method), and now your class can be called anywhere you like.

Comment: Makes sense,Thank you,.Yes it works,please see the edited answer with the solution i added below the question.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of keeping it inside an activity, you can create a common class(Common.java).  There create this method as a static method.

```
public static boolean connected(Activity activity){
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager=(ConnectivityManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo !=null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

Wherever you need this method call it like below.

```
Common.connected(activity);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a separate class which just checks for internet connection. And if you want to show snack bar then show in individual activity.

Code of Internet connection class:

```
public class InternetConnection
{
    private Context con;
    private static InternetConnection ic = null;

    public static synchronized InternetConnection getInstanceInternet(Context con)
    {
        if (ic == null)
        {
            ic = new InternetConnection(con);
        }

        return ic;
    }

    private InternetConnection(Context con)
    {
        this.con = con;
    }

    public boolean isNetworkAvailable()
    {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) con.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }
}
```

Usage of Above class:
Create a global object of the class and initialize it in on create of the activity. Then just check for it like this:

```
if (internetConnection.isNetworkAvailable())
{
    /// internet is avalable
}
else
{
    /// internet not available
}
```